# Azure B2C - how to add additional authentication field?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I want to add additional user input fields to my user logon page. Its trivial to add additional fields to a user registration page by adding a new claimType for my field and then referencing the claim as an OutputClaim as in the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom.

However when I add the same OutputClaim field to a standard logon journey such as SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email, it won't show the new field, but will fail validate with an error that my field is missing. Adding it as an InputClaim made no difference.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also tried this but ended up with same. I guess the workaround for this is adding one more page after Successful sign-in and get the additional values as input from the next self-asserted page. Also, if you add a new page that can work for both Social and Local accounts too.

Comment: My team were trying to add a hidden element to the page with the value of the redirect uri to use in a cancel button link (button is not there for this screen). We came up against the same issue as you face. In our case we could not use a second screen and still no solution as yet.

Answer (score 1):

> want to add additional user input fields to my user logon page.

No, it is not possible and it is by design.

**Workaround**

Adding one more page after Successful sign-in and get the additional values as input from the next self-asserted page.

**Advantage of adding new self-asserted page**

If you add a new page that can work for both Social and Local accounts too.